# V-Treeview activatable and open-on-click at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to have the possibility to click on the item name and it must have 2 comportment:

- expand it
- select it

I saw that by default it wasn't possible https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5947
But maybe someone here have an actual hack ?
Or is it actually against the component convention(rules) ?

Here is a sandbox if you wanna try some things:
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-https-esb6m?file=/App.vue

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```js
watch: {
   active(to, from){
      if (!this.open.includes(to)){
         this.open.push(to);
      }  
   }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

clear `open-on-click` props, add a `ref` on the treeview then
call

```js
@update:active="()=>{this.$refs.treeview.open.push(item[0])}"
```